# Avconv only converts 3 seconds of audio instead of the entire 30 minutes

Tags: conversion, mp3, avconv

this is my code

```
dir=Desktop/mp3convert #I left out the whole t
find "${dir:-.}" -name "*.mp3" -exec avconv -i {} -b 64k -ar 44100 -ac 1 {} \;
```

Comment: Have you tried not overwriting the files, but creating new files instead?  Currently you are trying to read from a file that you are also overwriting at the same time.

Comment: I have, and that does fix the problem, but then it seems i can not do this to multiple files at once. Like say convert 5 files as they will all be going into the same new file. I have tried to figure out how to recursively name the files using the find -exec option but i can not seem to come up with something that will work

Comment: What about: `find "${dir:-.}" -name "*.mp3" -exec avconv -i {} -b 64k -ar 44100 -ac 1 {}.new \;`

Comment: Good idea! I just tried, the problem is that it makes the output format .new and not .mp3 and thus the converter fails. if there was a way to rename inside the reclusive {}.....

Comment: `find "${dir:-.}" -name "*.mp3" -exec avconv -i {} -b 64k -ar 44100 -ac 1 new_{} \;`

Comment: First, thanks so much for all the thoughts, i think the problem is that find is passing dir/dir/dir/file.mp3 if it would only pass file.mp3 then the solution would be as stated above. I need to understand how find passes the file name better

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I wrote to complete the function i needed. I just used a loop to iterate through the directory instead of using find. much simpler now that I think about it. I will just have to keep all the files I want to downsample in the same directory which is fine for my purposes. Thanks for the help!

```
   #!/bin/bash
    export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/libffi/lib"
    export PKG_CONFIG_PATH="/usr/local/opt/libffi/lib/pkgconfig" 
    #because new mac os needs this to run ffmpeg

    cd /Users/timsutyak/Desktop/mp3convert
    ls #just to check that i am in the right location
    for name in *.mp3; do
      ffmpeg -i "$name" -map 0:a:0 -b:a 64k "${name%.*}_new.mp3"
    done
```